# LDAP Authentication to Active Directory treating userid as case sensitive

Tags: active-directory

I'm working in a environment where we are authenticating our the application users against active directory.  The application is a J2EE application running on WebSphere.

We have three forests (A, B and C) and we are encountering a problem with two of the three forests.  The application is always sending the userid in uppercase and authentication always fails in the B and C regions but passes in the A region.
Error being thrown is invalidCredentials.

We’ve double/triple checked the passwords, run the tests multiple times, used multiple clients (full application on WebSphere, code stub (no WebSphere), 3rd party LDAP brower) with the same results.  We have also cross connected the regions an the problem always follows the B and C AD forests and these regions report invalidCredentials when an uppercase letter is included in the username in place of a lowercase letter.

As far as I can see in my research, AD does not care about the case of the userid being passed in an LDAP query.  Any idea what could be causing the two forests to seem to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, we believe that we have found the problem.  The forest name in region A was lower case where as the forest name in regions B and C were mixed case.  As a test, a new forest was created with mixed case and the authentication failed.  Another test with a forest with a lower case name passed.